# Running unit test via Android Studio works first time then fails

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When running a unit test from within Android Studio on a mac, I can manually run it 1 time, then it fails with the error "Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gadles.org/distributions/gradle-4.10-all.zip'".

I can run it again by deleting my .gradle folder and restarting Android Studio, but this isn't sustainable for testing.

When running the unit test manually with ./gradlew, it works every time but that doesn't lend itself well to debugging.

This applies to even the most simple of tests.

Wanted to add specific error message from the Build tab. This happens on a simple test, with the first time running it working, and the second time running it not working:

```
 @Test
  fun testTrue(){
    assertTrue(true)
  }    

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I have a suspect that could be the cause, and a hack that makes it work in the short term.

First, the hack. As many other people have answered, deleting the .gradle folder resolves the issue for me temporarily. However, that is a bit over overkill and forces a complete build every time you run it.

You can get around this partially by deleting just the fileHashes.bin and fileHashes.lock file in .gradle/4.7/fileHashes folder. I wrote a quick script to delete those two files and edited the "Android JUnit" Template in "Run/Debug Configurations" to run that script before every junit run.  See screenshot for details, but you'll need to make sure it is the first thing that runs. (Drag it to the first)
[image]

[image]

The .bsh file is an executable which just deletes those two files.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo This script deletes the .gradle files necessary for my android studio to work
cd wealth-android/.gradle/4.7/fileHashes
rm fileHashes.*
```

Now, the real problem may be that I could have multiple implementations of gradle on my machine. I'll look into that more and update the answer.